# Adjusting layout of RadListView cells

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

NativeScript's `RadListView` doesn't properly respond to cell layout changes. Calling `refresh` on the list view is a *very* heavy-handed approach, as it destroys and recreates all cells.

Here is a Playground demonstrating the issue that I've run into with a side-by-side comparison of using `RadListView` and a `ngFor` cell generation: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=dG1G3n

For long lists, `ngFor` is awful as it constructs and loads *all* cells in the list, rather than just those that are currently on the screen. The `refresh` method is out because it rebinds all data, including those that are feeding into `async` pipes and may take time to populate (which is also not reflected in the cell UI).

There is a github issue on this topic which is closed: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/872. Does anyone have any advice for resolving this since this github issue is closed?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, as per your example you anyways want to refresh whole list view (all items in it). May be if it's one list item, you could refresh the specific item instead of entire list.

Comment: @Manoj The example I have provided was simply to demonstrate that the expected behaviour does not work. Refreshing the entire list is prohibitive when the list components perform asynchronous (potentially long-running) fetches. When a refresh occurs, it terminates all completed and in-progress fetches, then starts them all fresh.